# Moving a Team Project from one Collection to another - TFS 2015 Update 3

Tags: tfs, migrate

I'm trying to move a Team Project from one Team Collection to another, including check-in history, user stories and source code.

I'm running a TFS 2015 Update 3 setup, but the tools I found do not support this version.

Tools:

- http://tfsintegration.codeplex.com/
- https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/eb77e739-c98c-4e36-9ead-fa115b27fefe

Comment: There's no way to move team projects between collections other than by using third party tools. Tool recommendation questions are off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

**0. Create an empty collection** that will be used as a copy of DefaultCollection.
I called my second collection "TeamPrjectCollection"

**1. Make a Full Backup in TFS Administration Console**

[image]

**2. Detach the collection** that contains your Team Project

[image]

**3. Back up the collection database only** using SQL Management Studio.

[image]

**4. Restore database from backup to your empty collection**
Restore DefaultCollection from backup file into the empty Collection called "TeamPrjectCollection". You might get an error message during restore, make sure to open Options tab and check "Overwrite the existing database" and "Close existing connections to destination database". 
If you still get access error try do get DB offline restart the server and then back online the DB.
[image]

**5. Attach both collections** in TFS Administration Console
Select Tfs_DefaultDatabase DBs from the list and attach it, then select Tfs_TeamProjectCollection and attach it too with different Collection Name
. Ignore the warning at the end.

[image]

**6. Sort your Team Projects in both collections**
After your attach process second collection will go offline due to the warning message saying that your both team projects exist in both collections.

[image]

Simply remove `MyFirstProject` from 'TeamProject Collection'
and remove 'TeamProjectToMigrate' from 'DefaultCollection'
Bring 'TeamProjectCollection' online.

[image]

As can see both Collections are accessible from TFS

[image]

For more details please refer to Visual Studio documentation here: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/setup-admin/tfs/admin/move-project-collection

Answer (score 0):

As @Daniel mentioned in comment, there's no way to move team projects between collections other than by using third party tools. But this feature is under planned, you can track this [UserVoice](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services/suggestions/2037613-make-it-possible-to-move-a-team-project-between-te):

> We are committed to allow you to move team projects between
>   collections, although it’s currently not in scope for the 2016
>   calendar year. We’ll provide an updated timeline as we get closer to
>   2017.

Comment: I indeed already voted for this UserVoice. I just can't afford to wait so long, I was wondering if anyone on Stackoverflow already did this and could perhaps point me in the right direction

Comment: @TimVervers, there is no out-of-box feature to migrate team projects between collections, you may check some third party tools, like OpsHub: https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/28a90a17-d00c-4660-b7ae-42d58315ccf2